# autojump: /etc/profile.d/autojump.sh:.:20: no file :/etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh

Tags: centos, zsh

I have a VPS with centos and I want to use zsh, autojump.
first I install zsh:

```
yum install zsh
```

then, I install oh-my-zsh as its doc says and it works.
at last,I install autojump and add the autojump plugin to .zshrc.

```
........

plugins=(git autojump)

# User configuration

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
```

but when I login my vps with ssh,it displays:

```
/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh:.:20: no such file or dir: /etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh
```

I read the '/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh' and it will load 'autojump.zsh',but there is no file 'autojump.zsh'.

```
if [ "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [ -n "$PS1" ] && echo $SHELLOPTS | grep -v posix >>/dev/null; then
        . /etc/profile.d/autojump.bash
elif [ "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && [ -n "$PS1" ]; then
    . /etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh
fi
```

the files in dir "/etc/profile.d":

```
ls /etc/profile.d
autojump.bash  colorls.csh  cvs.csh  glib2.csh  lang.csh  less.csh  vim.csh  which2.sh
autojump.sh    colorls.sh   cvs.sh   glib2.sh   lang.sh   less.sh   vim.sh
```

if I need creat the 'autojump.zsh' myself?also,in my other vps I also installed autojump with zsh,it works well,why this can not work?
hope I describe my question clearly...

Comment: `yum install autojump`?

Comment: @4ae1e1 yes, I install autojump by yum

Comment: And it still doesn't work? Please post output of `ls /etc/profile.d/` or `ls /etc/profile.d/autojump*`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 in my opinion,there is no file named 'autojump.zsh', but it tries to load this file,I want to know how can I get this this,should I create it manually?

Comment: Yes that's what's happening here and that's rather strange because you installed it from your official package repository (did you? Or is it a community repo?). What's your version of `autojump`? I don't use CentOS and I can't find the package in http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/ so I can't really inspect what's wrong here. At any rate, I believe your version is dated, and I'd recommend just installing it from source, which is trivial: https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump#manual

Comment: It may just be that the package is aimed at typical users who generally stick with the default shell, Bash. Like @4ae1e1 suggests, you can either manually install it, or just manually copy the contents of that file from [GitHub](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/blob/master/bin/autojump.zsh).

Comment: @cyfur01 In the second case, one needs to take extra care to grab from the right version, though.

Answer (score 1):

To address this problem on CentOS, you should install the package autojump-zsh from EPEL, which provides /etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh:

```
# rpm -qf /etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh
autojump-zsh-19-2.el6.noarch
```

Something like this should do it:

```
yum install --enablerepo=base,epel autojump-zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

I Know how this problem happen,because I really have no file "autojump.zsh"。
I find one post,it explains how to solve this problem, its link is as following:
http://minyentw.blogspot.hk/2014/07/autojump-with-zsh-in-centos.html

Comment: This solution is not recommended. You are grabbing the file from a possibly incompatible version (the URI points to master), then trying to monkey patch it without understanding its contents. The right way is to install from git.